# GROUP CONCAT REPLACE sep strings

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, group-concat

I am using the below statement to pull a unique value off a table from a field that is separated with "|". It looks like this: "40|180|408|360|40|1s66|80|59" My problem is that I can't seem to get this statement to allow me to pull a primary key field, id, and assign it to each unique item from the field string so I can actually use it later. Ideally, ID # 27 should be assigned to each of the values on this temp table from "40|180|408|360|40|1s66|80|59". Can anyone help with the below statement to allow me to insert and assign field id to this from table BlogImageBundle?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (postId INT(11), val CHAR(255));
SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT      `images`) 
AS data FROM `BlogImageBundle`), "|", "'),('"),"');");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
SELECT DISTINCT(val) FROM test;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but ONLY for one record.  You will need to add another while loop that keeps track of the rowcount to deal with multiple records : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d62f7/1

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID          INT,
    Initial     VARCHAR(MAX)
)
CREATE TABLE #Test2
(
    ID      INT,
    Final   VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(27,'40|180|408|360|40|1s66|80|59')

DECLARE @String    VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @string = (SELECT Initial FROM #Test)

DECLARE @StringInput VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @stringInput = (SELECT Initial FROM #Test)  
WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', @StringInput) - 1, -1),LEN(@StringInput)))
    SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', @StringInput), 0),LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))
    INSERT INTO #Test2 (ID, Final)
    SELECT ID,@string FROM #Test
END
```